# How to make stargazer not to run while assigning

Tags: r, output, variable-assignment, stargazer

Let's take data :

```
library(plm)
library(stargazer)
# Create some random data
set.seed(1) 
x=rnorm(100); fe=rep(rnorm(10),each=10); id=rep(1:10,each=10); ti=rep(1:10,10); e=rnorm(100)
y=x+fe+e

data=data.frame(y,x,id,ti)

# Get plm within R2
summary.plm.full(plm(y~x,model="within",index=c("id","ti"), effect = "twoways", data=data))


data=data.frame(y,x,id,ti)

# Get plm within R2
reg=plm(y~x,model="pooling",index=c("id","ti"), effect = "individual", data=data) 
k <- stargazer(reg, type = "text", 
          add.lines = list(c("Overall R2", round(r.squared(reg, model = "within"), 3)),
                           c("Between R2", round(r.squared(update(reg, effect = "individual", model = "between")), 3))))
```

output :

```
========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                          y             
----------------------------------------
x                     1.183***          
                       (0.168)          
                                        
Constant               0.308**          
                       (0.151)          
                                        
----------------------------------------
Overall R2              0.53            
Between R2              0.174           
Observations             100            
R2                      0.337           
Adjusted R2             0.330           
F Statistic    49.751*** (df = 1; 98)   
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

But Why do I have an output of stargazer when I'm not running anything. It seems that stargazer gives output when I'm even assigning. What should I do make stargazer do not be run while assigning ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of `.stargazer.wrap()` (which is called by `stargazer()`), this is because `cat()` is widely used and always prints to the console, even if assigned.

Example:

```
x <- cat("hello")
```

Result:

```
hello
```

So the only way for you to assign the output of `stargazer()` without printing it is to ask the package maintainer to modify the function, but I doubt he/she will do it as `cat()` is very used throughout the function (and the package was not modified in the last two and half years).

You can take a look at [`texreg`](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg) as an alternative to `stargazer`.